# check if the name already exists in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a problem.
I have 2 `QTextEdit` fields : value & name.
When I push the button i create `QTableWidgetItem`s with the value from "value" and "name".
But now I will check if the name alredy exists.
But I don't know, with " findItems " ? with contain's ?
Tabelle extends from `QWidget` in the header.
I'am an c++/ QT Beginner and have no idea as I do that such.
PS: I'am speaking Germany, so you can answer in Germany, my English isn't very good ;D
Thank you :)

```
void Tabelle::pushButtonClicked() :

    strname = ( txtname ->text ());
    strvalue = ( txtvalue ->text ());
```

The textfields to Strings.

Put the vlaue in Items:

```
QTableWidgetItem * valueitem = new QTableWidgetItem(0);
valueitem->setText(strvalue);
QTableWidgetItem * nameitem = new QTableWidgetItem(0);
nameitem->setText(strname);
```

New row :

```
if (  cou >coucount )
    {table->insertRow(table->rowCount());}
    table->setItem( cou,1, valueitem );
    table->setItem( cou, 0,  nameitem); cou++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QList QTableWidget::findItems(const QString & text, Qt::MatchFlags flags) const.

As the doc says: 
 *Finds items that matches the text using the given flags.*

Try the following code:

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem *> ItemList = Table->findItems("TestName", Qt::MatchExactly); 
cout<< "Count:" << ItemList.count() << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks you for the fast answer.
must outside the method

Comment: Hauptsache es hilft :)

Comment: " QList<QTableWidgetItem *> ItemList = Table->findItems("TestName", Qt::MatchExactly); "
must outside the method, right ? 

and in my method i will check if they exist a Item like "TestName"
so i wrote 
if ( ItemList.count() == true ) ? 
or what returns finditems ? :D 
When it is false ( it isn't exist ) they shuld add the text .when it's true ( it exist ) the value shuldn't put in the Table

Comment: Haha Okey, forget it, it works :) !!!! perfekt ! Thank you very much 
I like this forum :)